Raspberry pi SPI / Dot Matrix LED with 74hc595n not work
I connect circuit like rasspbery pi - 595 - 595 - matrix.
Matrix turned on when i didn't transfer data.
However, run this code, it didn't work and turned off.
This is my spi library code which use gpio pin.
I will control the clock using gpio pin, and do data transfer through this.
from ..Library import GPIO_Library as GPIO
import time

def write_data(data, mosi_pin, sclk_pin):
    for byte in data:
        write_byte(byte, mosi_pin, sclk_pin)

def write_byte(byte, mosi_pin, sclk_pin):
    GPIO.set_value(sclk_pin , 0)
    for i in range (8):
        bit = (byte >> (7-i)) & 0x01
        GPIO.set_value(mosi_pin , bit)

        #toggle
        GPIO.set_value(sclk_pin, 1)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.set_value(sclk_pin, 0)
        time.sleep(0.00001)

def set_soft_spi(ss_pin = 0, mosi_pin = 0, miso_pin = 0, sclk_pin = 0):
    GPIO.export(ss_pin)
    GPIO.set_direction(ss_pin, "out")
    GPIO.set_value(ss_pin, 0)
    if(mosi_pin):
        GPIO.export(mosi_pin)
        GPIO.set_direction(mosi_pin, "out")
    if(miso_pin):
        GPIO.export(miso_pin)
        GPIO.set_direction(miso_pin, "in")
    if(sclk_pin):
        GPIO.export(sclk_pin)
        GPIO.set_direction(sclk_pin, "out")

def clear_soft_spi(ss_pin = 0, mosi_pin = 0, miso_pin = 0, sclk_pin = 0):
    if(ss_pin):
        GPIO.unexport(ss_pin)
    if(mosi_pin):
        GPIO.unexport(mosi_pin)
    if(miso_pin):
        GPIO.unexport(miso_pin)
    if(sclk_pin):
        GPIO.unexport(sclk_pin)


The experts on raspberry pi stack exchange site might be able to answer your question fairly quickly, faster than people on this site.

When you post your question over there, please include a schematic of your circuit.

You should enable the kernel module gpio-74x164 and spi-gpio (as you are using software SPI), it will make your life much more easier.
